# How to print the current running SQL statement when PrestoSQL/Trino CLI executes multiple statements from a file?

Tags: presto, trino, starburst

When I use trino or presto CLI with the `--file` option, I am only able to see the result of the queries on stdout. Is there any way to print the SQL statement before printing its result to stdout?